# Python exceptions example - LBYL vs EAFP

Tags: python, exception

So I think I get the idea of using EAFP in Python, but in applying it an example of my own feels like it makes the code less readable. I am writing a simple password generator function:

```
def generatePassword(length, letters, numbers, puntuation):
```

Where length is an int, and the other arguments are Booleans that describe the possible characters that make up the password.

I need to raise an exception if all 3 Boolean arguments are False. With a LBYL approach this is straightforward (and readable!), but it seems this is not best practice in Python.

If all 3 arguments are False, then an exception will be raised at this line in the function:

```
password += random.choice(charSet)
```

charSet is created based on the Boolean arguments, so if they are all False then charSet will be the empty string. The random library will then raise an IndexError. Okay fine, I catch that exception and raise my own (ValueError?).

First of all, is that even the right thing to do? Maybe it's just me, but I just find that a bit contrived - the error seems obscured and makes the code less readable perhaps? In my mind, it is clearer to start the function with something like:

```
if not(letters or numbers or punctuation): raise ValueError('my error msg')
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To my thinking, enforcing calling conventions is a fine place for LBYL. It's always an error to call your function with the three arguments all false, so it's clearer to raise that exception immediately. I'd also be sure to describe the restriction in the docstring.

EAFP is (again, my thinking) more for situations where you have a reasonable way to handle a specific exception that may arise.